# Synonyms for "prepared"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

"My team has prepared a website"

There is a synonym for "prepared" that fits better on this sentence?

Comment: Maybe "develop", as there is the job of "web developer"

Comment: Context, context, context.

Comment: "develop" sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As the OP agreed with my comment, I turn it into an answer)

Based on the fact that there exists a job called "web developer", my choice would be

> "My team has **developed** a website"

Answer (score 0):

The team is ready with a website....

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above - “developed” sounds good.

You could also say they have **’built’** or **’constructed’** a website, or use any synonyms like **’created’** , **’established’** , **’erected’** , **’set up’** etc.